# Convert PHP 2nd level json to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am try to convert json data in array but 2nd level json data not convert in array.

```
print_r($data);
```

=> output

```
id                   => 1
totalRecords         => 2
info                 => {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
```

use json

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
print_r($data);
```

=> output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [totalRecords] => 2
    [info] => {"id":1,"name":"abc"}
)
```

but not convert this data {"id":1,"name":"abc"} in array.

Comment: Why don't you try: $data['PassengerInfo'] = json_decode($data['PassengerInfo'], true)

Answer (score 0):

Supossing that you have this data array:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'id' => 1,
    'totalRecords' => 2,
    'info' => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'abc'
    ]
];
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($data)));
?>
```

It works fine and the output is:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [totalRecords] => 2 [info] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => abc ) )
```

Data var should has this array format, to convert it correctly.